# CodeIgniter Load Two views on a single onclick function

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

i want to load 2 views on a single click on onclick function.

I am using codeigniter and i want to load views through ajax.

so want to know how is it possible to load load two views in a single click and they both should load in different div's??

i managed to load only one in single div. but stuck on deciding what to do for loading two views.

Here is what i have done so far.

```
<a href='#' id=\"mnu_btn_user_accounts\" onclick=\"javascript:loadmenu('".base_url()."index.php/".$arLeftMenuList[$key]['FormCIPath']."')\">
```

below is the function of onloaod

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>

    function loadmenu(str){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: str,    
            success: function(output_string){    
                $('.second_column_content_container').html(output_string);    
            }    
        });
}
</script>
```

Any good solutions for my given problem?

Comment: You could pass both urls to the function as parameters, then load them with seperate ajax calls. Doesn't seem too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

onClick isn't necessary, nor really advised with jQuery, just set the two paths as separate classes in the link, then retrieve the classes in the links on click function and pass them to your ajax calls.

```
 <a href="#" id=\"mnu_btn_user_accounts\" class="link '.$arLeftMenuList[$key]['FormCIPath'].' '.$otherPath">Click Me</a>


<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
    $(".link").on("click", function(){
        var url1 = <?=base_url()."index.php";> + $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        var url2 = <?=base_url()."index.php";> + $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[2];
        loadmenu(url1, url2)
    {
    function loadmenu(url1, url2){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url1,    
            success: function(output_string){    
                $('.second_column_content_container').html(output_string);    
            }    
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url2,    
            success: function(output_string){    
                $('.other_content_div').html(output_string);    
            }    
        });
}
</script>
```